Show that the set $\{(x_k \cdot 2^{-k}) \mid x \in \ell_2\}$ is dense in $\ell_2$
I want to show that the set $A := \{(x_k \cdot 2^{-k}) \mid (x_k) \in \ell_2\}$ is dense in $\ell_2$.
My first attempt was that for any $(y_k) \in \ell_2$ also the sequence $(z_k) := (2^m \cdot y_k)$ is in $\ell_2$ for any $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and with that, construct for $(x_k) \in A$ a sequence of the type of $z$ with $\lVert x - y \rVert_{\ell_2} < \varepsilon$, but didn't come to a clue. Any help is appreciated!

Show that $A$ contains $c_{00}$, i.e., all sequences with only finitely many non-zero entries.

For $y \in \ell_2$, define $z_k^{(n)} = \begin{cases} 2^ky_k  & \text{if } k \leq n, \\ 0 & \text{if } k > n. \end{cases}\in \ell^2$
Let $x_k^{(n)} = 2^{-k}z_k^{(n)}  = \begin{cases} y_k & \text{if } k \leq n, \\ 0 & \text{if } k > n. \end{cases}\in A$
This allows you to approximate $y$ arbitrarily close.
